# How to take screenshot of UIView using NSThread?

Tags: ios, uiview, nsthread

I'm developing an app and I need to take the screenshot from a  thread. I'm unable to do this using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If anyone going to mark this question as duplicate, then please provide me a proper link to answer and take please care of this also that I am asking about creating image in thread.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9):

Unlike all the other answers want you to believe: That's not possible. UIKit is not thread safe, so doing anything, even just rendering the UI into a bitmap, is not guaranteed to work. You have to do that on the main thread I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, it is the all scenario that i am facing now but is there no way that I can create the UIImage of any UIView? Now I tried NSThread and NsOperation and use - (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg  method. But for all of them i am getting a web lock error and my application is crashed.

Comment: @Jack_iPhone No, it's not possible, no matter how you offload your code to another thread. The bit that takes the screenshot must be done on the main thread.

Comment: Per Apple documentation, all UIKit methods MUST be called on the main thread.  Notice that `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` (and all of the other methods that you are calling) start with `UI` and are therefore UIKit methods!

Comment: Thanks for your prompt feedback Sid. If you have time then take care of this problem and try to find a hint that can create the image of UIView other then on Main Thread. Please reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: @Jack_iPhone There is nothing I, or anyone else, can do about that. There is no clever trick or hidden mode, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Jack:  Again, notice that `UIView` and `UIImage` also start with UI.  That means that it must be created on the main thread.  If you want to change this, then suggest it to Apple!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a way to do this strictly in a thread, but can get you close.

Determine the size of the view, in pixels (ie retina or not), then create a bitmap context using `CGBitmapContextCreate`, allocate the memory, and set it all up, on a thread. You want to use BGRA on iOS (as I recall) but confirm this (using the proper layout results in faster drawing).

Now that you have the context, post a block to the main thread and draw into the context.

Once the `renderInContext:` finishes, post back to a background queue (or thread) to turn this bitmap into a CGImageRef and from that you can get a UIImage.

EDIT: this is taken from some code that I use with AVFoundation - I **think** this is what you will want but again try to confirm (its hard to find an absolute reference on the options that makes sense):

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); // same as CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
```

Note I had no use for alpha so the `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst`, but you will probably want it so use `kCGImageAlphaFirst`.